# Data source name will not show when connecting EF6 to Oracle 11g DB

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g

I am running VS2013 Pro on Win7 64 bit system.
I installed:

1. Oracle Developer Tools for VS 2013 (from Oracle)
2. ODP.NET Managed Driver (from Nuget)
3. ODP.NET Managed EF Driver (from Nuget)

However when I go to create a connection I see the following (see image).

If I click the search button it will find the Tnsnames.ora file however this dialog will not load that information.

How can I resolve this?

[image]

EDIT: tnsnames.ora

```
OracleTNS=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhostfromDB)(PORT=1592)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mySIDfromDB)))
```

EDIT 2: (Noticed this after a restart of PC and re launching my application)
[image]

Comment: is there anything in that file?  Sometimes oracle installs a file that has only comments.  Did you add your database information to the file?  Can you show us the contents of tnsnames.ora?

Comment: Yes there is info that I added.  Let me add it above.

Comment: Your tnsnames has the correct syntax. is Port 1592 correct? usually it is 1521.

Comment: Yes 1592 is the correct port

Comment: Stupid question, file permissions on the tnsnames.ora allow your user to read the file?

Comment: Good question, and yes I opened up permissions on that folder.

Comment: with that error message could this be the infamous bit issue, as in your 64 bit x does not work with your 32 bit y?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm real unfamiliar with Oracle to begin with.  However I had a similar PC that I was bale to connect to with VS and EF.  (This is a replacement PC to that one).  I checked all the settings between the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve this I uninstalled/reinstalled VS2013 and then installed Oracle Tools for VS.